# Img "Src Url " Add in Other "Src Url "in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On Click Id  "img1" image set in id "img2" and all the time keep an updated image on click.

`<button onclick="set1();">Save changes</button>`

```
<img id="img1" src="image1.png">
<img id="img2" src="image2.jpg">

  <script>
        function set1() {
            var elem = document.getElementById('img1').src;
        }
  </script>
```

What I am trying to ask is how do I finish the Javascript code that I started to change images with a button click.

Comment: You mean like this : `document.getElementById('img2').setAttribute('src', elem)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit simpler in `jquery`, I've added a demonstration below with placeholder images. It would also be a good idea to add a click event to the button from your script rather than inline, it's a little easier to manage.

Hopefully, this will help you get what you need - it demonstrates how to read an `attr` and set an `attr`.

---

```js
// Add click event to button
$("#saveButton").click(function() {

  // Get url from first image
  var url1 = $('#img1').attr("src");

  // Set the src url in the second image
  $("#img2").attr("src", url1);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="saveButton">Save changes</button>
<img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
<img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080">
```

Comment: I am using a different method, jquery it does not work. how can I write this code in js

Comment: You tagged the question with jQuery.  This is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

By just having one Image field, you can update its source when a button is clicked.

```html
<button onclick="updateImg();">Save changes</button>
<img id="img" src="image1.png">

<script>
    function updateImg() {
        img1Src = "image1.png";
        img2Src = "image2.jpg";
        var imgElem = document.getElementById('img');
        imgElem.src === img1Src ? imageElem.src = img1Src
                               : imageElem.src = img2Src; 
    }
</script>
```